How to fix and prevent "Multiple connections to a server or shared resource" for SMB shares between windows computers?
If you have two windows computers on the same network via Microsoft Account, you might have seen this error:
\\REMOTE_COMPUTER is not accessible. You might not have permission to use this network resource. Contact the administrator of this server to find out if you have access permissions.

Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again.

You'd think connecting Microsoft OS using Microsoft account that the company all but requires you to use would be easy, but it really isn't.
There is a closed stack-overflow question, however the two answers there do not work for me:

Restarting the workstation service does not seem to help, even restarting the local PC (the one that is connecting to REMOTE_COMPUTER) did not help
net use does not help, as it says "There are no entries in the list." so there are no connections to delete

Details of the problem:

Connecting from Windows 11 to Windows 10
Authenticating via Microsoft account, that means MicrosoftAccount\email@hosting.com
net use also does not show anything when the sharing works, meaning it might not really know about SMB connections on windows 11

Sometimes waiting and trying again helps, but by that time I can just copy the files using USB disk. What causes this? How can I prevent it from occurring? I only use single account, the error does not even make sense in my case.
I really don't understand why I still end up using USB flash drives in 2024 when working with Windows computers. I never encountered this when connecting from Windows to Linux SMB server.

The paragraph beginning with "You'd think connecting Microsoft..." isn't super clear. Perhaps this is just an aside? If so, I suggest that you remove it and some of the other meta-commentary or asides from question as they distract from the main point. You mention another question regarding this: can you provide a link to that other question? Did you try using IP addresses to connect? Did this make any difference?

@music2myear Thanks for the response. I will clear the question a bit and I did forget to add a link. I can see 4 close votes as "needs additional detail", but I don't know what detail to add. I can try IP, but I was using computer name on purpose so that I don't have to set up static IP for the other PC.

WANTING to use DNS is not the same thing as GETTING to use DNS. When I searched the error you mention, the results generally agree that you need to at least try using IP addresses as part of your diagnostic steps. As this was a common thread, this illustrates one reason you are earning close votes: It isn't clear that you've done much research or tried much on your own prior to asking. Do that and/or demonstrate it in the question and the question may be better received than it is in its current form.

If getting the error in VS that "Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed" then Use Below commands in CMD ran as Admin:
net stop workstation /y
net start workstation
** Beware though, using these commands will knock your permissions to other network  resources out until you close out of all File Explorer windows and reopen.
Good Luck h4k3r-322
